# Void/Unit type for calling the on_next function with no arguments

Tags: python, rx-py

I feel like I might be missing something very obvious here, but anyway...

When using RxPY, is there an equivalent of the C# RX `System.Reactive.Unit` type for calling the `on_next` function with no arguments?

```py
from rx import Observable

source = Observable.return_value(???)
source.subscribe(on_next=lambda: print("on_next called"))
```

If anyone is curious *why* I might want to do this, it's because I want the start function in the code below to be called without the `x` argument

```py
def on_start(func):
    def func_wrapper():
        Observable.return("").subscribe(func)
    return func_wrapper

@on_start
def start(x):
    print(x)

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, I was missing something obvious. I can just subscribe, receive the value and ignore it with a lambda.

```py
def on_start(func):
    def func_wrapper():
        Observable.return_value("").subscribe(on_next=lambda _: func())
    return func_wrapper

@on_start
def start():
    print("doh")

start()
```